# Is the induced map $\varphi$ on the homotopy cofibers null-homotopic in this situation?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
X & \xrightarrow{f} & * \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
Y & \xrightarrow{g} & Z 
\end{eqnarray}
be a (strictly) commutative diagram of pointed CW-complexes with $Y$ contractible. There is an induced map $$\varphi:\operatorname{h-cof(f)}\to \operatorname{h-cof(g)}$$
on the respective homotopy cofibers of the horizontal maps $f$ and $g$. No matter what model you choose for the homotopy-cofiber, the property of $\varphi$ to be null-homotopic (i.e. the property to factorize over the point $*$ up to homotopy) is independent of this choice.

> What is an example of a situation as above such that $\varphi$ is **not** null-homotopic?

I think I can show that $\varphi$ is null-homotopic, if $g$ was a cofibration but I presume that $\varphi$ may be non-null-homotopic, if $g$ was arbitrary. I can find an example if the upper-right corner $*$ of the initial diagram is replaced by an arbitrary contractible CW-complex, even if $g$ was a cofibration. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take $Y=\text{C}X$ the cone over $X$ and define your square to be cocartesian, i.e. as the (homotopy) pushout of $\text{C}X\leftarrow X\to\ast$. Then $\varphi: \text{cof}(f)\to\text{cof}(g)$ is an isomorphism since cocartesian squares glue.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know if the following related statement is true? Suppose you have an arbitrary strictly commutative square of pointed CW-complexes which is (by some reason) a homotopy-pushout square (and neiter necessarily a pushout not is anything a cofibration). Is the induced map on the homotopy cofibers an isomorphism? May I use the analog reason that homotopy-cocartesian squares glue?

Comment: Dear Jeffrey, yes, actually that's what I meant above - I should have written 'since homotopy-cartesian squares glue'

Comment: @jeffrey: I highly recommend to look at the abstracted notion of *derivator* which captures the essence of the formalism of homotopy limits and colimits. See http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/mgroth/papers/groth_derivators.pdf, where the glueing property of (homotopy) (co)cartesian squares is Proposition 3.13.